# JBoss Hibernate Library Conflict

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I'm having a problem hitting an Oracle DB when deploying to JBoss. Deploying to Tomcat works fine--No issue. I suspect the problem is related to a conflicting library that ships with JBoss. When I attempt to query the database (using Hibernate), I get the following:

```
2011-12-08 08:02:53,640 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/xxxx].[xxxx]] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-9) Servlet.service() for servlet xxxx threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseClassLoader@50d81341{vfszip:/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/web/deploy/xxxxx.war/} classLoader is not connected to a domain (probably undeployed?) for class oracle.sql.DATE
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:857)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:502)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:447)
```

Again, no such problem when running in Tomcat. I have set up a jboss-classloading file in my webroot the contains this:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    parent-first="false" domain="DefaultDomain" top-level-classloader="true"
    parent-domain="Ignored" export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true" />
```

But it doesn't seem to help. Strangely, I am connecting to two different databases with two different hibernate configurations, one Oracle 11i and one Oracle 8i. The Oracle 11 connection never throws a problem... Its only the 8i connection that causes this problem. The 11 connection works just fine.

I have no idea why this happens, but maybe JBoss contains an Oracle 8 Hibernate dialect lib and not the Oracle 11 dialect lib? In any case, how do I tell JBoss to use my packaged libraries and not the ones found on its classpath (assuming this is my problem)?

Comment: I need jboss-web.xml (in WEB-INF):

    <jboss-web>  
      <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">  
      <loader-repository>  
        com.talecris:archive=flint.war  
      <loader-repository-config>  
        java2ParentDelegation=false  
      </loader-repository-config>  
      </loader-repository>  
      </class-loading>  
    </jboss-web>

Comment: This is what we did on our jboss deployment, We removed all the hibernate jars from JBOSS server that did it. In our case the hibernate version on our app was not matching the jboss version.

Comment: The simplest way is to remove hibernate jars from jboss server  and put the jars on ur classpath. Else you would need to configure a jboss-web

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems root cause is the hibernate-validator, and I think you should add hibernate-validator-legacy if you are using maven you can use the following dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```